# uib-tooltip-html not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

From version 0.14 of ui-bootstrap, it looks like uib-tooltip-html (previsously : tooltip-html-unsafe) does not work anymore... or not the way I used to have it work.

Basicely, the 'tooltip' works when the 'tooltip-html' does not:

```
<a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="UIB-TOOLTIP-HTML">UIB-TOOLTIP-HTML</a>
<a href="#" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="UIB-TOOLTIP">UIB-TOOLTIP</a>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fJt3nBbT6rSbiN50h7Bp?p=preview

And since ui-bootstrap doc lacks example regarding this directive, I cannot guess what I am doing wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [example of the documentation of version 0.14](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.14.0/#/tooltip) definitely shows how to use it. Excerpts:

HTML:

```
I can even contain HTML. <a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="htmlTooltip">Check me out!</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.htmlTooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!');
```

[The latest doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) also has an example:

Html:

```
<p>
    I can even contain HTML as a
    <a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="htmlTooltip">scope variable</a> or
    <a href="#" uib-tooltip-html="'static. {{dynamicTooltipText}}. <b>bold.</b>'">inline string</a>
</p>
```

JS:

```
$scope.dynamicTooltipText = 'dynamic';
$scope.htmlTooltip = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!');
```

Comment: You're definitely write, and am definitely ashamed of my poor reading skills (don't say "lazynness"!). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding single quotation mark after the doubled ones did the job for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it like this (thanks to Herbi Shtini for pointing out the single quotation mark hack)

```
viewModel.tooltipContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('I\'ve been made <b>bold</b>!');

<div uib-tooltip-html="'{{main.tooltipContent}}'" tooltip-placement="bottom">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try like this i get html mix tool tip using **ubi-tooltip** given below

In JS.

```
app.controller("yoyoController", function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('Yo <b>Yo</b>');
});
```

In HTML

```
<div ng-controller="yoyoController">
    <p uib-tooltip-html="text" >
        A Thing With an HTML Tooltip
    </p>
</div>
```